# Illustrator CC guides not aligning to artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

I'm simply trying to align my guides (horizontal and vertical) to my Artboard directly in the middle.  I know there are other routes I could take to accomplish this, It should be something easily accomplished.  I have (unlocked) my Guides so that I am able to adjust them with the Selection tool as needed. I then select both guides with a simple bounding box, selecting them and altering the color to a dark blue rather than the (unselected) teal color. I make sure "Align to Artboard" is selected in the above Align Panel options, HOWEVER, when I hit the "Horizontal Align to Center" button and the "Vertical Align Center" button it aligns (not) to the Artboard but rather the entire document window (As seen in the attached image at the far bottom right of the screen).  Can anybody tell what I'm doing here that's incorrect?  I've checked various options and selections and can't tell.  Should be easily fixed I would assume... Thanks! :)

[image: Screenshot of Illustrator CC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Transform window, is your 'Align To Pixel Grid' checked? Try unchecking, then do the alignment. See if it works. [image: alignment]

Answer (score 0):

i've just got out from it.
try get the smart guides activated and uncheck this one
[image]

this works for me,
hope this could be any help for u too.